# Removing a listener from a parent method

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, listener

I'm trying to do an editor based on the CEditor but don't want a listener from one of its inherited methods, that comes in conflict with one of my features.

So I want to inherit the method but remove the listener and it's implementation from it.

Code looks like this:

```
class CEditor{
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        super.createPartControl(parent);

        final IWorkbenchHelpSystem helpSystem = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem();
        parent.addHelpListener(new HelpListener() {
            public void helpRequested(HelpEvent e) {
                IContextProvider provider = (IContextProvider) CEditor.this.getAdapter(IContextProvider.class);
                if (provider != null) {
                    IContext context = provider.getContext(CEditor.this);
                    if (context != null) {
                        helpSystem.displayHelp(context);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                helpSystem.displayHelp(ICHelpContextIds.CEDITOR_VIEW);
            }});
        ...
}}

class MyEditor{
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
            super.createPartControl(parent);
            Listener[] listeners = parent.getListeners(<<eventType>>);
            for (Listener listener : listeners)
                parent.removeHelpListener((HelpListener) listener);}
```

But it doesn't work it, the getListener(int eventType) method asks for an eventType and I don't know which event type number could be linked to the Listener I want.

Could anybody help me out?

How do I obtain the event type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWT has two types of listener. The low level listener which has an 'event type' code and the higher level 'typed listener'.

When you add a high level `HelpListener` a low level listener with event code `SWT.Help` is created and added to the listeners list.

`Control.getListeners` returns the low level listener class. There is no API to map from this Listener to the high level typed listener - so you can't get the `HelpListener`.

You can probably just call the `Control.removeListener(SWT.Help, listener)`
method to remove each of the low level listeners.

Comment: So you're telling me this can't be done? Do I have to use reflection to get rid of that annoying part of code from the CEditor?

Comment: You can probably just call the low level `removeListener` method - added to answer.

Comment: Ah yes, already did that instead of removeHelpListener. It removes the listener but apparently I misjudged my problem still isn't solved. The reason I wanted to remove that listener was because I wanted to remove the context sensitive help that comes with the CEditor. When I press F1 on some selected text it takes me to the help Related Topics, while I want to hook F1 to my automated search in help, for my editor.